# Correct syntax in stored procedure and method using MsSqlProvider.ExecProcedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have problem with ASP.net and stored procedure

My procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[top1000]
            @Published datetime output,
            @Title nvarchar(100) output,
            @Url nvarchar(1000) output,
            @Count INT output

AS 
SET @Published = (SELECT TOP 1000  dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_date_public FROM dbo.vst_download_files
    ORDER BY dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count DESC )
SET @Title = (SELECT TOP 1000  dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_name FROM dbo.vst_download_files
    ORDER BY dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count DESC) 
SET @Url = (SELECT TOP 1000  dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_source_url FROM dbo.vst_download_files
    ORDER BY dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count DESC) 
SET @Count = (SELECT TOP 1000  dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count FROM dbo.vst_download_files
    ORDER BY dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count DESC)
```

And my procedure in website project

```
public static void Top1000()
{
        List<DownloadFile> List = new List<DownloadFile>();
        SqlDataReader dbReader;

        SqlParameter published = new SqlParameter("@Published", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
        published.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlParameter title = new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        title.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlParameter url = new SqlParameter("@Url", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        url.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlParameter count = new SqlParameter("@Count", SqlDbType.Int);
        count.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        SqlParameter[] parm = {published, title, count};

        dbReader = MsSqlProvider.ExecProcedure("top1000", parm);

        try
        {
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
                DownloadFile df = new DownloadFile();
                //df.AddDate = dbReader["dfl_date_public"];
                df.Name = dbReader["dlf_name"].ToString();
                df.SourceUrl = dbReader["dlf_source_url"].ToString();
                df.DownloadCount = Convert.ToInt32(dbReader["dlf_download_count"]);
                List.Add(df);
            }

            XmlDocument top1000Xml = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode XMLNode = top1000Xml.CreateElement("products");

            foreach (DownloadFile df in List)
            {
                XmlNode productNode = top1000Xml.CreateElement("product");

                XmlNode publishedNode = top1000Xml.CreateElement("published");
                publishedNode.InnerText = "data dodania";
                XMLNode.AppendChild(publishedNode);

                XmlNode titleNode = top1000Xml.CreateElement("title");
                titleNode.InnerText = df.Name;
                XMLNode.AppendChild(titleNode);
            }

            top1000Xml.AppendChild(XMLNode);
            top1000Xml.Save("\\pages\\test.xml");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            dbReader.Close();
        }
    }
```

And if I made to `MsSqlProvider.ExecProcedure("top1000", parm);` I got

> String[1]: property Size has invalid size of 0.

Where I should look for solution? Procedure or method?

Comment: execute the procedure on `Sql Server Management Studio` and see if what is returned is what you're looking for. Also, using Visual Studio's debugger helps a ton in these situations.

Comment: Is this correct  `SqlParameter[] parm = {published, title, count};`? I think it should be `SqlParameter[] parm = {published, title, url, count};`

Comment: @Steve: I do it and `Command(s) completed successfully.`
@Pabloker: My typo, of course in my code it is with url :)

Comment: Your SQL in your sp seems screwy too, @Count is expecting you to return an int but you try to return 1000 rows in it? I'm not a pro, but that doesn't look right

Comment: @Steve I think I know what you trying to say, so I should use array

Comment: I don't even think you want to be using output parameters, but you haven't described what you're trying to achieve, just read the tables into an xml document?

Comment: I want take 1000 top downloaded elements and put therir name,date etc in to xml

Comment: You only need one query, no output parameters. I'd give an answer but I think you're so far off you'd just be better reading a few SQL and ADO tutorials. Don't worry about the XML yet, get the data first, then decide what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the length property for url and Title

```
SqlParameter title = new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar); 
title.Size=1000

SqlParameter url = new SqlParameter("@Url", SqlDbType.NVarChar); 
url.Size=1000
```

Instead of using an output parameter you can change your query like the one below

```
ALTER PRocedure [dbo].[top1000]
As
Begin 
Select top 1000 dfl_date_public ,dfl_name,dfl_source_url,
dfl_download_count from dbo.vst_download_files
order  by dbo.vst_download_files.dfl_download_count DESC
```

Then use execute reader

```
SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand("top1000", connection);
command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 // Iterate through reader as u did and add it to the collection
```

use xelement to frame the XML

```
   foreach (DownloadFile df in List) 
        {
   XElement products=
new XElement("Products",
    new XElement("product",
        new XElement("published", "data dodania"),
        new XElement("title", df.Name) 
                 );
         }
```

Comment: thanks, now I'm closer, now it tells me that Steve said. I have to select only one element.

Comment: You made my day with that comment xD and thanks for help you save my ass.